# MySQL error 1064 inner join

Tags: mysql

I write this SQL :

```
INSERT INTO registered (`idc`, `idp`, `date`)
SELECT 'idc' 
FROM course,registered
    INNER JOIN course c ON c.idc=registered.idc 
WHERE course.title='aaa',
      (SELECT `idp` FROM participant,registered
      INNER JOIN participant ON participant.idp=registered.idp WHERE 
      participant.username='mmm')
```

I get this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '
>       (SELECT `idp` FROM participant,registered    INNER JOIN participant ON pa' at line 4

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

course
idc int(11)PRI auto_increment
title varchar(200) UNI
details text
participant
idp int(11)PRI auto_increment
firstname varchar(50) 
lastname varchar(50)
username varchar(100)UNI
registered
idc int(11) unsigned PRI
idp int(11) unsigned PRI
date date

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like this where you set a parent SELECT with the two other SELECT statements after it...

```
INSERT INTO registered (idc, idp, date) 
  SELECT 
    (SELECT 'idc' FROM course, registered INNER JOIN course c ON c.idc=registered.idc WHERE course.title='aaa'), 
    (SELECT idp FROM participant,registered INNER JOIN participant ON participant.idp=registered.idp WHERE participant.username='mmm');
```

Also, you'll likely need to set "date" as well. If it's set automatically based on the definition for that column, you can leave it out:

```
INSERT INTO registered (idc, idp)...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your insert sentence expects 3 values: `(`idc`,`idp`,`date`)` but your select sentence only supply one: `SELECT 'idc'`

You should redefine your query as:

```
INSERT INTO registered (`idc`, `idp`, `date`)
SELECT course.idc, participant.idp, <HERE A DATE> 
FROM registered
    INNER JOIN course ON course.idc = registered.idc
    INNER JOIN participant ON participant.idp = registered.idp
WHERE 
    course.title = 'aaa'
    and participant.username = 'mmm';
```

But your INSERT sentence expects a date field as a 3rd field, you must supply it.

Comment: every time that i find a solution it appear a new error!!

Comment: your select statement should return 3 fields basically.

Comment: My goal is to insert into the table registered idc and idp or the title is unique  ('aaa') and the same thing for the username of the participant is 'mmm'

Comment: could you post your table schema?

Comment: course idc int(11)PRI auto_increment title varchar(200) UNI details text participant idp int(11)PRI auto_increment firstname varchar(50) lastname varchar(50) username varchar(100)UNI registered idc int(11) unsigned PRI idp int(11) unsigned PRI date date